# drawing an orthogonal list in latex

Tags: lists

an orthogonal list is a direct generalization of a linked-list.here is a picture :
[image]

The picture is not very accurate but 
basically it looks like a matrix with some null elements. Each no-null element has two pointers, one to the first no-null element on its right, and another points down to the first no-null element  below it. 
 I'm wondering how do you draw an orthogonal list in latex:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make some preparations to get the shapes and the extra vertical and/or horizontal lines, and dashes, you can either use the `chains` or `matrix` libraries to draw this very easily. The advantage of `chains` is that you do not have to draw the horizontal arrows explicitly, and the advantage of `matrix` is that you do not need to type `node` so often.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,matrix}
\tikzset{c/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=4em,text width=2em,align=center},
    h/.style={path picture={
    \draw ([yshift=1em]path picture bounding box.west)
     -- ([yshift=1em]path picture bounding box.east)
     ([yshift=-1em]path picture bounding box.west)
     -- ([yshift=-1em]path picture bounding box.east);}},
    v/.style={path picture={
    \draw ([xshift=-1em]path picture bounding box.north east)
     -- ([xshift=-1em]path picture bounding box.south east)
     (path picture bounding box.west)
     -- ([xshift=-1em]path picture bounding box.east);}},
    dt/.style={append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode.center) ++ (-0.7ex,1.2em) edge ++(1.4ex,1.4ex)}}, 
    db/.style={append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode.center) ++ (-0.7ex,-1.2em) edge ++(1.4ex,-1.4ex)}}, 
    dr/.style={append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode.center) ++ (1.2em,-0.7ex) edge ++(1.4ex,1.4ex)}}, 
    arj/.style={-Stealth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[start chain=R1 going right,
    nodes={c,on chain,join=by arj}]      
    node[h,dt,alias=1]{1}
    node[v]{1\\[1ex] 10} node[v]{2\\[1ex] 8} node[v,dr]{3\\[1ex] 4};
 \path[start chain=R2 going right,
    nodes={c,on chain,join=by arj}]      
    node[h,below=of 1,alias=2]{2}
    node[v]{2\\[1ex] 8} node[v]{1\\[1ex] 3} node[v]{4\\[1ex] 5}
    node[v,dr]{3\\[1ex] 6};
 \path[start chain=R3 going right,
    nodes={c,on chain,join=by arj}]      
    node[h,below=of 2,alias=3,db]{3}
    node[v]{1\\[1ex] 4} node[v]{2\\[1ex] 7} node[v,dr]{4\\[1ex] 3};
 \path[arj] (1.-120) edge (2.120) (2.60) edge (1.-60)
    (2.-120) edge (3.120) (3.60) edge (2.-60) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={c,anchor=center},column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm] (m){
|[h,dt,alias=1]|{1} & |[v]|{1\\[1ex] 10} & |[v]|{2\\[1ex] 8} & |[v,dr]|{3\\[1ex] 4}\\
|[h,alias=2]|{2} & |[v]|{2\\[1ex] 8} & |[v]|{1\\[1ex] 3}  & |[v]|{4\\[1ex] 5} & |[v,dr]|{3\\[1ex] 6} \\
|[h,alias=3,db]|{3} & |[v]|{1\\[1ex] 4} & |[v]|{2\\[1ex] 7} & |[v,dr]|{4\\[1ex] 3} \\
};
\path[arj] (1.-120) edge (2.120) (2.60) edge (1.-60)
    (2.-120) edge (3.120) (3.60) edge (2.-60) 
    foreach \Z in {1,2,3} {foreach \X[count=\Y] in {2,3,4}
    { (m-\Z-\Y) edge (m-\Z-\X)}}
    (m-2-4) edge (m-2-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]